# When I withdraw SS vs when I retire

Tags: united-states, retirement, social-security

If I stop working at age 65, can I wait to age 70 to accept SS (living off of my own retirement accounts and younger spouse's income) for those 5 years?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, in fact, that's a good strategy for most.

You can always change your mind, if things change. In general, be aware of the benefit you'll get if you request early benefits, at 62, full benefits, at about 66, or adjusted, higher benefits for each year you delay until 70. 8%/yr increase, plus cola, by the way.

A bit of a tangent to your question - during the years before you draw SS, consider partial Roth conversion of some of your 401(k) or IRA money. This would (possibly)  help you reduce the amount of SS subject to tax. Look up how SS is taxed as you receive it, and see if you would be in that income range. Not knowing the numbers that apply to you, I can't say much more than that.

Comment: 10 years to go means this is the best time for you to start doing all of the research. Depending on your current income and what tax bracket you land in you might consider starting your Roth conversions now and doing them over the next 10 years.it's a matter of understanding your marginal tax rate, and going to the Social Security website to see what your benefit would be and how it would be potentially be taxed as you receive it.

Comment: A Roth conversion would mean paying tax now to avoid taxes later?

Comment: Yes. If you are in retirement, at right at the point where $1000 in income will be taxed, but also cause $850 of SS to be taxed, this strategy can help you. I wrote about it a bit in this article http://rothmania.net/the-phantom-tax-rate-zone/

Comment: Did you ever get the MFJ version?

Comment: Scroll down, link to next post. You can see how you might think you are in 25% bracket, but the effect of SS taxation puts you at 47.5%. If conversions at 25% can pull down post retirement income you can come out ahead. It's a matter of analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I expect this is because your ss benefits age will be 70, but you're actually retiring at 65.  Yes, you don't get social security unless you, or a caregiver applies for it.  It takes a bit to process as well, so apply 3 months before you turn 70 (can't do earlier if your full benefits start at 70).  The application will have a start date for your benefits, you'll fill in the day you turn 70, so your benefits will start exactly on time.